# How to permanently hide the update notification in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The "Restart and update" notification is so annoying, showing up every single day. How to get rid of it forever? I can't stand seeing it every time i start Visual Studio Code.[image]

Comment: Why don't you just restart and install the update?

Comment: Why do that every single day?

Comment: Because if you update it it won't ask you again?

Comment: But it will ask when the next update is available?

Comment: If you don’t like fast-moving software, use something else. Atom receives fewer updates. That being said, the change mentioned in David’s answer has now been implemented.

Comment: @DanielB, I've never seen an update notification for Store apps neither for Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to get rid of it forever?

It is not currently possible, and there is a feature request to improve this from an SE employee ([Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver)) (see below).

You might want to contribute to this discussion.

Having said that there have already been some changes made:

> we have lightened the update notification in the insiders build, no changes in stable for June. More details can be found in the test plan item [#27454](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/27454). Please give it a try.
>
> [insiders build](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/01/introducing_insiders_build) today: http://code.visualstudio.com/Download#insiders

Source [Too many update prompts for users - and suggested alternatives](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24823).

> you are no longer spammed by the message service once there is an update

Source [Test: light update in activity bar #27454](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/27454)

---

#### Too many update prompts for users - and suggested alternatives

> What I don't like is the consumption of these updates at an ever-increasing frequency as a user. The promise of Visual Studio Code
>   is a release approximately once a month. But that's (understandably)
>   not reality, because software has bugs and release have unexpected
>   issues in the wild.
>
> ...
>
> I propose the following requirements, as a user consuming updates:
>
> - Should not get a prompt to update two days in a row (this has happened many times)
> - Should not get a prompt to update more than once a week on a channel called "stable"
>
> A few ideas:
>
> - A "slow" channel, where releases are only posted if they has been no new release in the past 7 days.
>
>   - This would have eliminated the > 1 per month prompts for not-really-stable releases for 9 of the 10 months they happened in the
>       table above.
> - Give users an option to configure a similar lag, not prompting for an update until it has been posted for at least 7 days and not
>     obsoleted by a new point release.
>
>   - e.g. update.delayDays, which if configured to 7 days would have the same effect as above.
> - Make updates a background post-close operation, simply informing the user in a much more subtle way (0-clicks, auto-dismiss) that an
>     update will occur on next restart automatically.
>
> The bottom line is VS code is a means to an end. I'm trying to do
>   work, and so is everyone else. Update prompts, especially repetitive
>   ones in a short duration get in the way of that and only add
>   frustration. They rarely help me get any work done; it's usually the
>   opposite.
>
> Thoughts? Ideas? Can we improve this?

Source [Too many update prompts for users - and suggested alternatives](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24823).

Comment: One option to block the updates is using the firewall. 